# Laravel through relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multi level relation in my app

```
Category

 |products

  |product_items

   |product_group

    |product_attributes
```

Category Model

```php
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Product Model

```php
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductItem2::class);
}
```

Item Model

```php
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeValue::class,'product_groups','item_id','attribute_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Attribute value

```php
public function attributeName(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class,'attribute_id');
}
```

all relations works fine but now I need filter my product by example 'colors'

so I tried

```php
 return $this->where('parent_id',0)->whereHas('childrenRecursive')->with('products.items.attribute.attributeName')->get();
```

put of course it return all categories with all product and product items etc

here is the migration files

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('cover')->nullable();
        $table->string('url')->nullable();
        $table->string('cover');
        $table->text('url_cover');
        $table->text('description')->nullabel();
        $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id');
        $table->boolean('elite')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('category_product',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->primary(['product_id','category_id']);
    });
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('serial_number');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('discount');
        $table->enum('type',['pound','percentage']);
        $table->timestamp('start')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('end')->nullable();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->unsignedInteger('shop_id');
        $table->boolean('recommendation');
        $table->boolean('published');
        $table->integer('preparing_days')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('visits')->defualt(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('priorty')->defualt(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('product_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->unsignedInteger('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('product_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('attribute_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('item_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('attribute_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('attribute_id');
        $table->string('value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

all i need to return the attribute 'color' values like `['red,blue,black']` with each category 
seems complicated and need help.

Comment: We need more information, what is the `$this` in `$this->where('pare...` ? and where you're running this code ?

Comment: sorry i missed that , this return in my filter method to return to api to show the available colors in filter for each category to send to filter with it. I will update it

Comment: We also don't know from where the `colors` comes...

Comment: I come from last relation `attributeName()` it returns attribute_id and the value 'red'

Comment: Does your `return`, return the correct rows? You just want only the colour instead of all of the data?

Comment: Yes it does, but the return `category[product[items[attributes_values]]]` and that will not be acceptable for an api.

Comment: Do you want to return the categories that have at least one of the three colors? Or all of them?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I hope to return the category with the color that added to its products

Comment: Please post the migrations for the involved tables.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: The value of `attributes.name` would be `color`?

Comment: yes will be `color` and `attribute_values.value` will be `red` for example